# Java card SIM toolkit applet

Tags: applet

I'm going to develop SIM toolkit applet using eclipse.

I create new java card project and add sim and toolkit packages provided by 3GPP 43.019 specification
And my codes are here.

```
package com.example.TestPackage;

import javacard.framework.*;
import javacardx.annotations.*;
import static com.example.TestPackage.TestStkAppletStrings.*;
import sim.toolkit.*;
import sim.access.*;

/**
 * Applet class
 * 
 * @author <user>
 */
@StringPool(value = {
        @StringDef(name = "Package", value = "com.example.TestPackage"),
        @StringDef(name = "AppletName", value = "TestStkApplet")},
        // Insert your strings here 
    name = "TestStkAppletStrings")
public class TestStkApplet extends Applet implements ToolkitInterface, ToolkitConstants
{

    public static final byte CMD_QUALIFIER          = (byte)0x80;
    public static final byte MY_INSTRUCTION         = (byte)0x46;
    
    private byte[] menuEntry =    {(byte)'0',(byte)'3',(byte)'.',(byte)'1',(byte)'9',(byte)' ',(byte)'A',(byte)'p',(byte)'p',(byte)'l',(byte)'e',(byte)'t'};
    
    private byte[] menuTitle=     {(byte)'M',(byte)'y',(byte)'M',(byte)'e',(byte)'n' ,(byte)'u'};
    private byte[] item1 =        {(byte)'I',(byte)'T',(byte)'E',(byte)'M',(byte)'1' };
    private byte[] item2 =        {(byte)'I',(byte)'T',(byte)'E',(byte)'M',(byte)'2' };
    private byte[] item3 =        {(byte)'I',(byte)'T',(byte)'E',(byte)'M',(byte)'3' };
    private byte[] item4 =        {(byte)'I',(byte)'T',(byte)'E',(byte)'M',(byte)'4' };
    private Object[] ItemList =   { item1, item2, item3, item4 };
    private byte[] textDText =    {(byte)'H',(byte)'e',(byte)'l',(byte)'l',(byte)'o',(byte)' ',
      (byte)'w',(byte)'o',(byte)'r',(byte)'l',(byte)'d',(byte)'2'};
    
    private byte[]  baGSMAID =    {(byte)0xA0, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x09, (byte)0x00, (byte)0x01};
    private ToolkitRegistry reg;
    private SIMView gsmFile;
    private byte buffer[] = new byte[10];
    private byte itemId;
    private byte result;
    
    public TestStkApplet() {
        // get the GSM application reference
        gsmFile = SIMSystem.getTheSIMView();
        // register to the SIM Toolkit Framework
        reg = ToolkitRegistry.getEntry();
        // Define the applet Menu Entry and register to the EVENT_MENU_SELECTION
        itemId = reg.initMenuEntry(menuEntry, (short)0x0000, (short)menuEntry.length, 
                                   PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT, false, (byte) 0x00, (short) 0x0000);
    }
    
    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
        TestStkApplet MyStkApplet = new TestStkApplet();
        MyStkApplet.register();
    }

    @Override
    public void process(APDU apdu) {
        //Insert your code here
        if(selectingApplet())
            return;
        switch(apdu.getBuffer()[1]) {
            // specific APDU for this applet to configure the MenuTitle from SelectItem
            case (byte)MY_INSTRUCTION:
                if(apdu.setIncomingAndReceive() > (short)0) {
                    Util.arrayCopy(apdu.getBuffer(),(short)0x0005,menuTitle,(short)0x0000,(short)0x0006);
                }
            break;

            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void processToolkit(byte event) throws ToolkitException {
        EnvelopeHandler          envHdlr = EnvelopeHandler.getTheHandler();
        ProactiveHandler         proHdlr = ProactiveHandler.getTheHandler();
        ProactiveResponseHandler rspHdlr ;
        boolean repeat;     
        
        switch(event) {
            case EVENT_MENU_SELECTION:
                // Prepare the Select Item proactive command
                proHdlr.init(PRO_CMD_SELECT_ITEM,(byte)0x00,DEV_ID_ME);
                // Append the Menu Title
                proHdlr.appendTLV((byte) (TAG_ALPHA_IDENTIFIER | TAG_SET_CR),
                                 menuTitle,(short)0x0000,(short)menuTitle.length);
                // ask the SIM Toolkit Framework to send the proactive command and check the result
                if((result = proHdlr.send()) == RES_CMD_PERF) {
                    rspHdlr = ProactiveResponseHandler.getTheHandler();
                    switch (rspHdlr.getItemIdentifier()) {
                        case 1:
                            // DisplayText High Priority 
                            proHdlr.init(PRO_CMD_DISPLAY_TEXT, CMD_QUALIFIER,DEV_ID_DISPLAY);
                            proHdlr.appendTLV((byte)(TAG_TEXT_STRING| TAG_SET_CR), DCS_8_BIT_DATA,
                                                textDText,(short)0x0000, (short)textDText.length);
                            proHdlr.send();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            break;  
        
        }       
    }
}
```

As I run it and start simulator, it returns error in creating and selecting applet.
The errors in eclipse here.

```
CMD>// Copyright (c) 1998, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
// Applet Instantiation APDU Script
//
// Package:     TestProject
// Package AID: //aid/1111111111/
// Applet:      com.example.TestPackage.TestStkApplet
// Applet AID:  //aid/1111111111/11
//
// Select the installer applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x09 0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x62 0x03 0x01 0x08 0x01 0x7F;
APDU|CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 09, a0, 00, 00, 00, 62, 03, 01, 08, 01, Le: 00, SW1: 90, SW2: 00
// Create com.example.TestPackage.TestStkApplet applet
0x80 0xB8 0x00 0x00 0x08 0x06 0x11 0x11 0x11 0x11 0x11 0x11 0x00 0x7F;
CREF|
CREF|throw_error(NULL_POINTER_EXCEPTION)
APDU|CLA: 80, INS: b8, P1: 00, P2: 00, Lc: 08, 06, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 00, Le: 00, SW1: 64, SW2: 44
CMD>// Copyright (c) 1998, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
// Applet Selection APDU Script
//
// Package:     TestProject
// Package AID: //aid/1111111111/
// Applet:      com.example.TestPackage.TestStkApplet
// Applet AID:  //aid/1111111111/11
//
// Select com.example.TestPackage.TestStkApplet applet
0x00 0xA4 0x04 0x00 0x06 0x11 0x11 0x11 0x11 0x11 0x11 0x7F;
APDU|CLA: 00, INS: a4, P1: 04, P2: 00, Lc: 06, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, Le: 00, SW1: 6d, SW2: 00
```

I don't know how I fix it.
In addition, I want to ask more questions.

1. Simulator does not support SIM toolkit ?
2. What is the INS b8 means? is there any specification I can refer?
3. I don't know exactly how I import sim.toolkit.* and sim.access.*. please explain it in details.

Could someone explain to me?
Please let me know about it.